# TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2

Tags: python

This is my code and I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
```

How do I fix?

[image]

Comment: What is the use of answer list created?

Comment: You are not using answer list.In the if else statement you can use aos == answer[1] and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems clear to me.  The `input` function expects one parameter -- the prompt string -- and you have provided two.  I don't know what you were trying to do with the `[]`, but you need to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

`aos` `input()` doesn't accept `[]` as second parameter. You can send it as string from conse not like array.

Answer (score 2):

I read your entire code and I think what you mean to do is

```
aos = input("Are you adding or subtracting")
answer = ['Adding','Subtracting']
```

And then after that in the if statements

```
if aos == answer[0]:
   print("The solution is",sol1)
elif aos == answer[1]:
   print("The solution is",sol2)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! It worked.....I was trying to make a code that would solve the quadratic formula.

Comment: If the answer worked, do accept my answer by clicking on the tick next to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
aos = input("Are you adding or subtracting:", [])
```

with

```
aos = input("Are you adding or subtracting:")
```

As the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) method takes in a maximum of 1 argument, keyword or positional.